# What is Market share for open source web-GIS systems?

Tags: geoserver, web-mapping, comparison, geomajas, deegree

I would like to know the market share of 3 web-GIS systems, deegree, GeoServer, Geomajas).

Which one is more popular?

Are there any evaluations regarding the market share of open source web-GIS systems?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with GIS-Jonathan, you're comparing things that are not on the same level. Ok for deegree and GeoServer (they're not quite the same thing but they're GIS engines working on the server side of your solution), but GeoMajas is another thing, it's a framework to build web applications. In any case, if you want compare open source products you could use [Ohloh](http://www.ohloh.net/): it's very useful!
Bye!
Cesare